# Does git always produce stable results when doing a pull?

Tags: python, git

I'm building a little python script that is supposed to update itself everytime it starts. Currently I'm thinking about putting MD5 hashes on a "website" and downloading the files into a temp folder via the srcipt itself. Then if the MD5 Hashes line up the temp files will be moved over the old ones.

But now I'm wondering if git will just do something like this anyway.

What if the internet connection breaks away or power goes down when doing a git pull? Will I still have the "old" version or some intermediate mess?

Since my aproach works with an atomic rename from the os I can at least be shure that every file is either old or new, but not messed up. Is that true for git as well?

Comment: Git is atomic if that is what you ask.

Comment: I think that's what I'm asking. But just to make sure: Does that mean that I will have either the new or the old version, but never a broken mess or missing files? (if there was no merge or anything, but a straight pull)

Comment: It's not atomic when performing a merge, which is what you're asking for with pull. If it's not straightforward, it will stop in the middle and ask the user to fix and continue.

Comment: @CarlosMartínNieto I dont think the asker wants to actually use it in a way that would merge anything

Comment: But that's what you're asking git to do if you call pull. If you don't want to merge, you should't ask git to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A pull is a complex command which will do a few different things depending on the configuration. It is not something you should use in a script, as it will try to merge (or rebase if so configured) which means that files with conflict markers may be left on the filesystem, which will make anything that tries to compile/interpret those files fail to do so.

If you want to switch to a particular version of files, you should use something like `checkout -f <remote>/<branch>` after fetching from `<remote>`. Keep in mind that git cannot know what particular needs you have, so if you're writing a script, it should be able to perform some sanity checks (e.g. make sure there are no extra files lying around)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think it missed my problem. In my case there won't be any merge or rebase operations since I don't edit the script on the remote box. I just want it to update itself to the latest version from the same repository over and over again.

Comment: That's a pretty big assumption you're making there. If anything changes on either side, it's going to attempt a merge. If that's not what you want, then you shouldn't use it. Aside from that, it's only meant for usage directly by a user, which is why it stops in the middle of processing and puts files with merge conflict markers on the working directory.

Comment: Well, what if I clone the repository in a temp folder, check for errormessages & warnings and then use the script to rename / move files to override the existing ones?

Comment: As long as your script knows how to perform the deployment, that would work, it comes down to what the script does in the end, as in this situation you'd be using git as a file transfer mechanism.